# wxPython Button to load multiple images

Tags: python, image, button, wxpython

Right, a back story. For my university project I am creating a rhythm teacher for the drums. So what the program will do is load up a drum notation, and an audio file matching that drum notation. The user presses the "Play" button, and it plays a short drum beat that matches the notation. So far I've got a button to play a loaded Wav. file, and another button to load up an image. I hope I'm making sense.

So my question is, does anyone have a function that will do this? As in, a button to load an image and an audio file together. And if the button is pressed again, it'll load another image and audio file, overwriting whatever was loaded before. I'll have a fair amount of images and audio files to load. Important bit is that the image has to match the audio file.

Again, I have a button that plays an audio file, another that just loads an image (I did this since I'm a newbie and was just learning how to do these functions.

I'll post a code anyway, and it should make more sense! Sorry if it's a long read! Just thought I'd put a back story on what I'm doing.

```
import wxversion
wxversion.select("2.8")
import wx
import wx.media

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    title = "Main Menu"

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
     wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Window', size=(1000,700))
     panel=wx.Panel(self, -1)

     self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(100,100,100))
     self.Centre()
     self.Show()

     status=self.CreateStatusBar()

     menubar=wx.MenuBar()
     filemenu=wx.Menu()
     exitmenu = filemenu.Append(wx.NewId(),"Exit", "Exit Program")

     menubar.Append(filemenu,"File")
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onExit, exitmenu)
     self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

     font1 = wx.Font(30, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, u'Consolas')

     Text1=wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Rhythm Trainer", (10,15))
     Text1.SetFont(font1)
     Text1.SetForegroundColour('white')

     btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label='Basic', pos=(100,200), size=(150, 50))
     btn1.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

     self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.newwindow, btn1)

     btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label='Advanced', pos=(100,270), size=(150, 50))
     btn2.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

     btn3 = wx.Button(panel, label='Notations', pos=(100,340), size=(150, 50))
     btn3.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

     btn4 = wx.Button(panel, label='Settings', pos=(100,410), size=(150, 50))
     btn4.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

     btn5 = wx.Button(panel, label="Quit", pos=(820, 550), size=(150, 50))
     btn5.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, btn5)

    def OnClick(self, event):
     self.Close()

    def OnQuitButton(self, event):
     wx.Sleep(1)   
     self.Destroy()

    def onExit(self, event):
     self.Destroy()

    def newwindow(self, event):
     secondWindow=window2(parent=None, id=-1)
     secondWindow.Show()

class window2(wx.Frame):

    title = "new Window"

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
     wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Window2', size=(1000,700))
     panel=wx.Panel(self, -1)

     self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(100,100,100))
     self.Centre()
     self.Show()

     status=self.CreateStatusBar()

     menubar=wx.MenuBar()
     filemenu=wx.Menu()
     exitmenu = filemenu.Append(wx.NewId(),"Exit", "Exit Program")

     menubar.Append(filemenu,"File")
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onExit, exitmenu)
     self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

     font2 = wx.Font(30, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, u'Consolas')

     Text2=wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Rhythm Trainer", (10,15))
     Text2.SetFont(font2)
     Text2.SetForegroundColour('white')
     self.Show(True)

     btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label="Back", pos=(820, 550), size=(150, 50))
     btn1.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, btn1)

     btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label="Play", pos=(820, 100), size=(150, 50))
     btn2.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onPlaySound, btn2)

     btn3 = wx.Button(panel, label="Stop", pos=(820, 150), size=(150, 50))
     btn3.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onStopSound, btn3)

     btn4 = wx.Button(panel, label="Next", pos=(820, 200), size=(150, 50))
     btn4.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.loadImage, btn4)
     self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, pos=(50,50), size=(800, 200))

    def loadImage(self, event):
      image_file = 'Rock-beats.jpg'
      bmp = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
      wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, -1, bmp, pos=(200, 50), size=(417, 133))



     # def onNext(self, event):
        """
        Calls the nextPicture method
        """
        #self.nextPicture()

    def onPlaySound (self, event):
      sound = wx.Sound('Test3.wav')
      sound.Play(wx.SOUND_ASYNC)

    def onStopSound(self, event):
     wx.Sound.Stop()

    def onExit(self, event):
      self.Destroy()
      wx.Sound.Stop()

    def OnClick(self, event):
      wx.Sound.Stop()
      self.Close()

if __name__=='__main__':
 app=wx.PySimpleApp()
 frame=MainWindow(parent=None,id=-1)
```

Code 2.0 for Unutbu- Here's my full runnable code -

```
import wxversion
#wxversion.select("2.8")
import wx
import wx.media
import itertools as IT
import os

IMAGE_DIR = './'
SOUND_DIR = './'

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    title = "Main Menu"

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
     wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Window', size=(1000,700))
     panel=wx.Panel(self, -1)

     self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(100,100,100))
     self.Centre()
     self.Show()

     status=self.CreateStatusBar()

     menubar=wx.MenuBar()
     filemenu=wx.Menu()
     exitmenu = filemenu.Append(wx.NewId(),"Exit", "Exit Program")

     menubar.Append(filemenu,"File")
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onExit, exitmenu)
     self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

     font1 = wx.Font(30, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, u'Consolas')

     Text1=wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Rhythm Trainer", (10,15))
     Text1.SetFont(font1)
     Text1.SetForegroundColour('white')

     btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label='Basic', pos=(100,200), size=(150, 50))
     btn1.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

     self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.newwindow, btn1)

     btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label='Advanced', pos=(100,270), size=(150, 50))
     btn2.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

     btn3 = wx.Button(panel, label='Notations', pos=(100,340), size=(150, 50))
     btn3.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

     btn4 = wx.Button(panel, label='Settings', pos=(100,410), size=(150, 50))
     btn4.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

     btn5 = wx.Button(panel, label="Quit", pos=(820, 550), size=(150, 50))
     btn5.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, btn5)

    def OnClick(self, event):
     self.Close()

    def OnQuitButton(self, event):
     self.Destroy()

    def onExit(self, event):
     self.Destroy()

    def newwindow(self, event):
     secondWindow=window2(parent=None, id=-1)
     secondWindow.Show()
     self.Close()

 class window2(wx.Frame):

    title = "new Window"

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
     wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Window2', size=(1000,700))
     panel=wx.Panel(self, -1)
     self.images = IT.cycle([filename for filename in os.listdir(IMAGE_DIR) if filename.endswith('.jpg')])
     self.image_file = None
     #self.images = IT.cycle(os.listdir(IMAGE_DIR))
     #self.image_file = next(self.images)    

     self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(100,100,100))
     self.Centre()
     self.Show()

     status=self.CreateStatusBar()

     menubar=wx.MenuBar()
     filemenu=wx.Menu()
     exitmenu = filemenu.Append(wx.NewId(),"Exit", "Exit Program")

     menubar.Append(filemenu,"File")
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onExit, exitmenu)
     self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

     font2 = wx.Font(30, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, u'Consolas')

     Text2=wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Rhythm Trainer", (10,15))
     Text2.SetFont(font2)
     Text2.SetForegroundColour('white')
     self.Show(True)

     btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label="Back", pos=(820, 550), size=(150, 50))
     btn1.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, btn1)

     btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label="Play", pos=(820, 100), size=(150, 50))
     btn2.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onPlaySound, btn2)

     btn3 = wx.Button(panel, label="Stop", pos=(820, 150), size=(150, 50))
     btn3.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onStopSound, btn3)

     btn4 = wx.Button(panel, label="Next", pos=(820, 200), size=(150, 50))
     btn4.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
     self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.loadImage, btn4)
     self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, pos=(50,50),  size=(1000, 180))



    def loadImage(self, event):
      #image_file = 'Rock-beats.jpg'
      #bmp = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
      #wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, -1, bmp, pos=(200, 50), size=(417, 133))
       self.image_file = next(self.images)
       image_file = os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, self.image_file)
       bmp = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
       width = bmp.GetWidth()
       height = bmp.GetHeight()
       wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, -1, bmp, pos=(200, 50), size=(width, height))
       wx.Sound.Stop()
       print(self.image_file)

     # def onNext(self, event):
     #"""
     # Calls the nextPicture method
     # """
     #self.nextPicture()

    def onPlaySound (self, event):
      #sound = wx.Sound('Test3.wav')
      #sound.Play(wx.SOUND_ASYNC)
       sound_file, ext = os.path.splitext(self.image_file)
       sound_file = os.path.join(SOUND_DIR, sound_file + '.wav')
       sound = wx.Sound(sound_file)
       sound.Play(wx.SOUND_ASYNC) 
       print(sound_file) 
       def onStopSound(self, event):
       wx.Sound.Stop()

    def onExit(self, event):
      self.Destroy()
      wx.Sound.Stop()

    def OnClick(self, event):
      wx.Sound.Stop()
      self.Close()
      mainwindow=MainWindow(parent=None, id=-1)
      mainwindow.Show()

if __name__=='__main__':
 app=wx.PySimpleApp()
 frame=MainWindow(parent=None,id=-1)
 frame.Show()
 app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: How do you know what is the filename of the next picture, and which `.wav` file it is associated with?

Comment: Well I'll name them in accordance to each other. Example image and .wav file will be called "notation1" etc. But that's probably going to be the main problem, to load them together. Just thought I'd ask if anyone has some idea to do this. I'm quite stumped and a newbie in Python.

Comment: notation1.wav, notation1.jpg

Comment: I've been searching for how to do it. But usually a google search just comes back with "bitmap buttons" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it:

- First, define global variable(s) defining the directory which
  contains the images and wav files:

  ```
  IMAGE_DIR = '/path/to/images'
  SOUND_DIR = '/path/to/sounds'
  ```

  You could use the same directory if you wish. I'm going to assume that

  - all the images are JPEG files that end with `.jpg`,
  - if an image is called `foo.jpg` then the associated wav file is
    called `foo.wav`.
- Next, in the `window2.__init__` method define two new attributes:

  ```
  self.images = IT.cycle([filename for filename in os.listdir(IMAGE_DIR) if filename.endswith('.jpg')])
  self.image_file = None
  ```

  and at the top of the file, import the `itertools` module:

  ```
  import itertools as IT
  ```

  `os.listdir(IMAGE_DIR)` returns a list of filenames. The [IT.cycle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)
  returns an iterable that cycles through the items in the list *ad
  infinitum*.

  [next(self.images)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) returns the items in the iterable
  `self.images` one at a time -- a different one with each call to
  `next`. We'll use this below.
- Now, `loadImage` might be written like this:

  ```
  def loadImage(self, event):
      self.image_file = next(self.images)
      image_file = os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, self.image_file)
      bmp = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
      wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, -1, bmp, pos=(200, 50), size=(417, 133))
  ```

and to play the associated wav file:

```
   def onPlaySound(self, event):  
        sound_file, ext = os.path.splitext(self.image_file)
        sound_file = os.path.join(SOUND_DIR, sound_file + '.wav')
        sound = wx.Sound(sound_file)
        sound.Play(wx.SOUND_ASYNC)
```

Since [os.path.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) and [os.path.splitext](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) are being used, be sure to import the `os` module at the top of the file too.

---

Here is the code you posted with the suggested changes:

```
import wxversion
wxversion.select("2.8")
import wx
import wx.media

import itertools as IT
import os

IMAGE_DIR = os.path.expanduser('~/tmp/images')
SOUND_DIR = os.path.expanduser('~/tmp/sounds')


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    title = "Main Menu"

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Window', size=(1000, 700))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(100, 100, 100))
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

        status = self.CreateStatusBar()

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        filemenu = wx.Menu()
        exitmenu = filemenu.Append(wx.NewId(), "Exit", "Exit Program")

        menubar.Append(filemenu, "File")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onExit, exitmenu)
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        font1 = wx.Font(
            30, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, u'Consolas')

        Text1 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Rhythm Trainer", (10, 15))
        Text1.SetFont(font1)
        Text1.SetForegroundColour('white')

        btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label='Basic', pos=(100, 200), size=(150, 50))
        btn1.SetFont(
            wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.newwindow, btn1)

        btn2 = wx.Button(
            panel, label='Advanced', pos=(100, 270), size=(150, 50))
        btn2.SetFont(
            wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

        btn3 = wx.Button(
            panel, label='Notations', pos=(100, 340), size=(150, 50))
        btn3.SetFont(
            wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

        btn4 = wx.Button(
            panel, label='Settings', pos=(100, 410), size=(150, 50))
        btn4.SetFont(
            wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))

        btn5 = wx.Button(panel, label="Quit", pos=(820, 550), size=(150, 50))
        btn5.SetFont(
            wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, btn5)

    def OnClick(self, event):
        self.Close()

    def OnQuitButton(self, event):
        wx.Sleep(1)
        self.Destroy()

    def onExit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

    def newwindow(self, event):
        secondWindow = Window2(parent=None, id=-1)
        secondWindow.Show()
        self.Close()


class Window2(wx.Frame):

    title = "new Window"

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Window2', size=(1000, 700))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(100, 100, 100))
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

        status = self.CreateStatusBar()

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        filemenu = wx.Menu()
        exitmenu = filemenu.Append(wx.NewId(), "Exit", "Exit Program")

        menubar.Append(filemenu, "File")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onExit, exitmenu)
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        font2 = wx.Font(
            30, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, u'Consolas')

        Text2 = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Rhythm Trainer", (10, 15))
        Text2.SetFont(font2)
        Text2.SetForegroundColour('white')
        self.Show(True)

        btn1 = wx.Button(panel, label="Back", pos=(820, 550), size=(150, 50))
        btn1.SetFont(
            wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick, btn1)

        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label="Play", pos=(820, 100), size=(150, 50))
        btn2.SetFont(
            wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onPlaySound, btn2)

        btn3 = wx.Button(panel, label="Stop", pos=(820, 150), size=(150, 50))
        btn3.SetFont(
            wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onStopSound, btn3)

        btn4 = wx.Button(panel, label="Next", pos=(820, 200), size=(150, 50))
        btn4.SetFont(
            wx.Font(14, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, 0, u'Consolas'))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.loadImage, btn4)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1, pos=(50, 50), size=(800, 200))

        self.images = IT.cycle(
            [filename for filename in os.listdir(IMAGE_DIR)
             if any(filename.lower().endswith(ext) 
                    for ext in ('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'))])
        self.image_file = next(self.images)

        img = wx.EmptyImage(240,240)
        self.imageCtrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 
                                         wx.BitmapFromImage(img), pos=(200, 50))

    def loadImage(self, event):
        self.image_file = next(self.images)
        print(self.image_file)
        image_file = os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, self.image_file)
        img = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        img = img.Scale(240,240)
        # The idea of using imageCtrl.SetBitmap comes from
        # http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/26/creating-a-simple-photo-viewer-with-wxpython/
        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))

    def onPlaySound(self, event):
        sound_file, ext = os.path.splitext(self.image_file)
        sound_file = os.path.join(SOUND_DIR, sound_file + '.wav')
        print(sound_file)
        sound = wx.Sound(sound_file)
        sound.Play(wx.SOUND_ASYNC)

    def onStopSound(self, event):
        wx.Sound.Stop()

    def onExit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()
        wx.Sound.Stop()

    def OnClick(self, event):
        wx.Sound.Stop()
        self.Close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MainWindow(parent=None, id=-1)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I am a bit befuddled by the behavior you are describing. Here's why: When you press the `Next` button, the `loadImage` method is run. This method only changes the image, it does not play any sound. So how could it be that "Pressing the next button will only load up the next .wav file".

Comment: Here is a suggestion: Put `print(self.image_file)` in the `loadImage` method, and put `print(sound_file)` in the `onPlaySound` method. This might give us a clue as to what is going on when the `Next` and `Play` buttons are pressed. If that does not shed enough light on the situation, please post your full code.

Comment: I have not been able to reproduce the behavior you describe. I'm posting the code I am using. Please compare it with your own. And if you are still having trouble, post your complete runnable code so I can try reproducing the problem.

Comment: Okay, I think I might finally be seeing the problem. Instead of inserting more and more images into the panel, we should insert only once, and then call `SetBitmap` to change the image. I've updated my post to show what I mean.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, since I am just getting an error - 
img = img.Scale(240,240)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'img' referenced before assignment

Comment: ah my bad I forgot to put img = wx.Image(image_file, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY) in the LoadImage function! Took me a while to figure that one out haha I'll test it further with more images and audio, and get back with the results. In mean time, I really appreciate your help! Definitely helped me understand and learn a bit more on python!

Comment: Right, seems like I don't really need the img = img.Scale. The function does kind of work, but not with the first hit of the next Button. Pressing the next button first seems to load the second image rather than the first, but it doesn't display anything, just says "Notation2.jpg" in the python shell. Pressing the next button again, finally loads notation1.jpg and displays it correctly. From there everything loads perfectly. It's just the first two presses on the Next button that seems to be a bit buggy.

Comment: When opening the second window, and just pressing play it plays the first .wav file, when it should have the first image displayed along with it. There's also a weird black box when opening the second window up. I've also noticed, when it actually loads the first image, pressing the next button it will disappear then load the second image. Pressing it again will just kind of load the first image on top of the second (their not scaled properly, since their sized differently), so I expect it to be something to do with that there's only 2 images so far.

Comment: Quite sorry if I'm taking up your time and just coming back with errors and errors!

Comment: Chudboy, these aren't errors, these be mission creep! :) The original question was how to cycle through a series of images when you pressed a button. I think I've given you enough code to do that. If you study how it works -- how `self.image_file` is defined in `__init__` and used in `loadImage` and `onPlaySound` -- I'm sure you can modify it so the image you desire is displayed upon initialization.

Comment: And yes you have given me enough code! Greatly appreciated! I'll definitely work through it. I will need to make my own notations anyway, all the same image size. So I guess because I've just loaded random images for now, it might of caused a few hiccups! But cheers, you've helped me a lot! Sorry if I've been a pain!